# Dynamic checkbox to enable textbox

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, dynamic, textbox

I have a problem about dynamic controls. I create a dynamic userform with single frames depending by a number (rngprt in my example dependent by user input). No problem till now. Now I want to enable a textbox (in order to change its value) inside a specific frame when the relative checkbox is click. I used a Class Module (Classe1), but with my code I succeeded  only to enable the last textbox of the n-frames when its checkbox is clicked (e.g. if I have 3 frames with 3 textboxes and 3 checkboxes, only the third checkbox it's able to enable the third textbox, the first and the second don't work).

Class Module: Classe1

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents cmbEvent1 As MSForms.CommandButton
Public WithEvents txbEvent1 As MSForms.TextBox
Public WithEvents frmEvent1 As MSForms.Frame
Public WithEvents ckbEvent1 As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub cmbEvent1_Click()
UserForm3.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub frmEvent1_Click()
End Sub

Public Sub txbEvent1_Change()
End Sub

Private Sub ckbEvent1_Click()
If UserForm3.Controls("CK" & xx).Value = True Then
UserForm3.Controls("TB" & xx).Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
```

Module: UserForm3

```
Option Explicit
Dim cmdB As New Classe1
Dim txtB As New Classe1
Dim chkB As New Classe1
Dim frm As New Classe1
Dim chkBColl As New Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim x As Long
Dim c As Variant
Dim cmdB1 As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim frm1 As MSForms.Frame
Dim txtB1 As MSForms.TextBox
Dim chkB1 As MSForms.CheckBox

Set cmdB1 = UserForm3.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
       With cmdB1
            .Name = "OKButton"
            .Caption = "OK"
            .Top = 40 * rngprt
            .Left = 120
            .Width = 40
            .Height = 25
       End With
       Set cmdB.cmbEvent1 = cmdB1

For x = cel.Row To cel.Row + rngprt - 1 '**rngprt is a number from a Module1**

xx = x - cel.Row + 1  '**for progessive name of controls Dim xx as long into the Module1**

Set frm1 = UserForm3.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1")
            frm1.Top = 40 * (xx - 1)
            frm1.Left = 10
            frm1.Width = 300
            frm1.Height = 35
            frm1.Name = "FR" & xx

With frm1.Controls

Set txtB1 = .Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
       With txtB1
            .Name = "TB" & xx
            .Top = 10
            .Left = 160
            .Width = 30
            .Height = 15
            .TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
            .Enabled = False
            .Value=50
       End With
       Set txtB.txbEvent1 = txtB1

     Set chkB1 = .Add("Forms.CheckBox.1")
       With chkB1
            .Name = "CK" & xx
            .Caption = "Part"
            .Top = 10
            .Left = 245
            .Width = 45
            .Height = 15
       End With
       Set chkB.ckbEvent1 = chkB1
       'Here I added the code below

End With
       Set frm.frmEvent1 = frm1
Next x

End Sub
```

I tried also to add this code below the chkB1 setting, but nothing.

```
       Set chkB = New Classe1
       Set chkB.ckbEvent1 = Me.Controls(chkB.txbEvent1)
       chkBColl.Add chkB
```

Anybody have idea. Thank in advance to all for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will not work.

You need to create an array of classe1. 
Check this changes:

Classe1

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents cmbEvent1 As MSForms.CommandButton
Public WithEvents txbEvent1 As MSForms.TextBox
Public WithEvents frmEvent1 As MSForms.Frame
Public WithEvents ckbEvent1 As MSForms.CheckBox

Public xx As Integer

Private Sub cmbEvent1_Click()
UserForm3.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub frmEvent1_Click()
End Sub

Public Sub txbEvent1_Change()
End Sub

Private Sub ckbEvent1_Click()
If UserForm3.Controls("CK" & xx).value = True Then
UserForm3.Controls("TB" & xx).Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
```

UserForm3

```
Dim cmdB() As New Classe1
Dim txtB() As Classe1
Dim chkB() As Classe1
Dim frm() As New Classe1


Dim chkBColl As New Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim x As Long
Dim c As Variant
Dim cmdB1 As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim frm1 As MSForms.Frame
Dim txtB1 As MSForms.TextBox
Dim chkB1 As MSForms.CheckBox
ReDim Preserve cmdB(1)
Set cmdB1 = UserForm3.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
       With cmdB1
            .Name = "OKButton"
            .Caption = "OK"
            .Top = 40 * rngprt
            .Left = 120
            .Width = 40
            .Height = 25
       End With
       Set cmdB(0).cmbEvent1 = cmdB1

For x = cel.Row To cel.Row + rngprt - 1 '**rngprt is a number from a Module1**

xx = x - cel.Row + 1  '**for progessive name of controls Dim xx as long into the Module1**

    ReDim Preserve txtB(xx)
Set txtB(xx) = New Classe1
Set frm1 = UserForm3.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1")
            frm1.Top = 40 * (xx - 1)
            frm1.Left = 10
            frm1.Width = 300
            frm1.Height = 35
            frm1.Name = "FR" & xx

With frm1.Controls

Set txtB1 = .Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
       With txtB1
            .Name = "TB" & xx
            .Top = 10
            .Left = 160
            .Width = 30
            .Height = 15
            .TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
            .Enabled = False
            .Value=50
       End With
       txtB(xx).xx = xx
       Set txtB(xx).txbEvent1 = txtB1

ReDim Preserve chkB(xx + 1)
Set chkB(xx) = New Classe1
     Set chkB1 = .Add("Forms.CheckBox.1")
       With chkB1
            .Name = "CK" & xx
            .Caption = "Part"
            .Top = 10
            .Left = 245
            .Width = 45
            .Height = 15
       End With
       Set chkB(xx).ckbEvent1 = chkB1
       chkB(xx).xx = xx
       'Here I added the code below

End With
ReDim Preserve frm(xx)
       Set frm(xx).frmEvent1 = frm1
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Jorge Ribeiro. It works fine. Just for curiosity, if I would that when checkbox was deselected the relative textbox will restored to default value (i.e. 50 in my example) and also will disabled the textbox? Is possible to do it?

Comment: Yes, you can add a property on classe to store the value, and restore it on the click event (if state of checkbox is checked)

Comment: Great. Thank you Jorge. Could you suggest me the code for this option, please?

Comment: something like that:
first declare:
private value as string
then change the code
Private Sub ckbEvent1_Click()
If UserForm3.Controls("CK" & xx).value = True Then
UserForm3.Controls("TB" & xx).Enabled = True
value = UserForm3.Controls("TB" & xx).Text
else
UserForm3.Controls("TB" & xx).Text = value
End If

Comment: Ok, I tried something similar `Private Sub ckbEvent1_Click()
Dim tx As Variant
 tx = UserForm3.Controls("TB" & xx).Value
If UserForm3.Controls("CK" & xx).Value = True Then
 UserForm3.Controls("TB" & xx).Enabled = True
Else
 UserForm3.Controls("TB" & xx).Enabled = False
 UserForm3.Controls("TB" & xx).Value = tx
End If
End Sub` it works partially, but when checkbox is deselected the textbox value doesn't return to starting value if changed it before deselecting checkbox